# Is the following Feynman diagram (given in Schwartz) wrong?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, textbook-erratum

For the process $e^+e^-\rightarrow \gamma \gamma$ Schwartz gave following Feynman diagram in section 9.4

[image: FD]

I think the diagram is wrong since it didn't conserve charge at both the vertices. The correct diagram should have an internal propagator of either $e^-$ or $e^+$. Also, the particle flow direction for $e^+$ in the lower-left section should be in reverse direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake you mention was in the first edition and should have been corrected in future editions of the book. See errata here: schwartzqft.fas.harvard.edu/first-edition-corrections. Make sure you work with the fourth (latest) edition since there were many small mistakes (and a couple big ones) in the book. The mistakes in the diagram are 1) internal line should be a scalar and 2) the arrows should be reverse in the e^+ line.

Comment: the virtual should be an $e^-$ arrow from top to bottom. electrons are not scalars. $e^+$ usualy a positron read  as an electron with the arrow in the opposite direction to the momentum.

Comment: I usually see ghost fields represented with dotted lines

Comment: @annav in that section he is doing scalar QED so the “electrons” are scalars.

Comment: @Triatticus ghost fields have dotted lines. Scalars have dashed lines.